# Discord Widget One way CSS Transformation

Tags: css

Pretty new to CSS design,

I'm trying to get my discord widget to transform two ways on hover and off hover,

There is a nice transition when I hover over the discord widget which expands slowly and when I take the mouse off resets to its originally position.
What I'm trying to do is help transition back to its original position in the same way it does when I hover over the widget

So far I've only managed to it work on hover

```
.disc-widget {

    position: fixed;
    top: 16%;
    right: 75px;
    
    
    border-radius: 5px;

} 

.disc-widget :hover{
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);

}
```

I've even tried this and still doesn't work

```
.disc-widget {

    position: fixed;
    top: 16%;
    right: 75px;
    
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all transform 0.5s;
} 

.disc-widget :hover{
    
    transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    
}
```

I don't know if it's because of the  part of the widget that is maybe keeping me from doing it or the I'm just not doing the CSS right.

Comment: Can you try to improve the question? Your expectations as a user? It is not really clear what th code is supposed to do.

Comment: Basically trying to get the discord widget to transform (expanding outward)  and inward with the same effect when ever I hover my mouse over the widget and off of the widget, currently I'm not able to make the widget slowly transition inward back to its original size